# Vertically aligned text in math

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

How do I get something like this in LaTex? I have tried the align-environment, but can't get the vertical text (argmin) right.[image]

Comment: (1) welcome (2) the xy or (perhaps better) tikz-cd package

Comment: there's traditionally a thin space in `arg\,min`.

Answer (score 4):

You get better arrows with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0pt]
\displaystyle\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} q(w_{i},\theta)
  \arrow[r]
&
\mathbb{E}[q(w,\theta)]
\\
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\argmin$}
&
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\argmin$}
\\
\hat{\theta} \arrow[r,red] & \theta
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For example, environment `array` can be used for the alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \DeclareMathOperator
\usepackage{dsfont}   % for \mathds
\usepackage{color}    % for \color{red}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    N^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} q(w_i, \theta)
    & \longrightarrow & \mathds{E} [q(w, \theta)] \\[1.5ex]
    \rotatebox{90}{$\argmin$} & &
    \rotatebox{90}{$\argmin$} \\[1ex]
    \hat\theta & \color{red}\longrightarrow & \theta_0
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `alignat`,and `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts} %
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\Exp}[1]{\mathbb{E}}[]{}{#1}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} %
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage{eqparbox}
    \newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{alignat*}{2}
   \eqmathbox[ML]{ N^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} q(w_i, \theta)}
    & \longrightarrow{} & \eqmathbox[MR]{\Exp{q(w, \theta)}} \\%[1.5ex]
    \eqmathbox[ML]{\rotatebox{90}{$\argmin$}} & &
    \eqmathbox[MR]{\rotatebox{90}{$\argmin$}} \\[-0.7ex]
    \eqmathbox[ML]{\hat\theta} & \color{Crimson}\longrightarrow & \eqmathbox[MR]{\theta_0}
  \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]